# Relationship between REST API & Database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, api, rest

I've been studying databases and rest APIs lately and I have a question about the relationship between the two.

Imagine I have a database with three tables, STUDENTS, ENROLLED, and CLASSES.

STUDENTS and CLASSES denote the entities students and classes, whereas the ENROLLED table denotes their relationship.

If I were to map this dataset in a rest api, would I just have 3 different CRUD routes with the three tables, eg ('/students', '/classes', '/enrolled')?

And that question goes for REST APIs in general -- when you write/make a REST API, are you just constructing a 1:1 mapping of your database?

Thanks so much in advance-- just trying to really nail down my conceptual understanding of the relationship between the two.

Cheers!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer

Comment: You might be better off over here, as this is a bit more theoretical: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You design your **service** in a way that it is meaningful and convenient to your clients.

Comment: In general, you should disconnect your database structure from your business layer. In this case the tables happen to nicely line up with what will end up being your business objects, but that won't always be the case. Simply assuming that your front end will use basic crud against tables in your database is usually a bad assumption, IMO.

Comment: @dgig when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Answer (score 0):

HTTP verbs are mostly used for CRUD operations but while writing/ making a REST API you are not necessarily constructing a 1:1 mapping of your database.

Rest can have hypermedia controls. Like if somebody wants to to get a doctors appointment he first needs to get the available appointment slot and than using that appointment slot he can make a request to make an appointment. While delivering the available appointment slot you can send the url for booking that slot.

Read this - http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html